# What does mean the "Warning: Cannot determine link type" in Talend Open Studio

Tags: java, excel, talend

I´m importing 3 excel files into my database using a simple routine (Download files from server to local -> Iterate over those 3 files -> Convert Strings to Id's in catalogs in tMap and send to the same table in database)

[image]

First two files dont have any problem but third one is showing:

> Warning:  Cannot determine link type

after "my_excel" component. Anyone knows why this message appears?

Comment: Do you mean "at the end of the tJava" or do you have a routine used in tMap? Can you share this code?
What's the condition associated to the "if"

Comment: Could you post the whole output of the job?

Comment: @tobi6 The output is just that simple message in the console =( rigth after the job finished.

Comment: @Antonycx In that case I would disable component after component and see which one is causing the error.

Comment: @tobi6 Ok, i found is not related with talend process. It was because i have a URL in 1 column of my excel pointing to a not found google drive document. Seems to be thats the problem. This URL is saved in the database with no problem. Ty for your comments =)